# composer.phar guzzlehttp/guzzle installation error

Tags: php, laravel-5, guzzle

i am running command
c:/xampp/htdocs/cloud>  php composer.phar require guzzlehttp/guzzle

getting error could not open file composer.phar 
anyone help me with this error thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just try it this:

```
> composer require guzzlehttp/guzzle
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the path for composer.phar or you need to copy the composer.phar to /usr/local/

Comment: Thanks Sujit,
i have install composer now error is 
Fatal error: Class 'Illuminate\Foundation\Application' not found in /path/to/project/bootstrap/app.php on line 14

Comment: Now you need to run "composer update" on root directory